# function to run over selected columns with dplyr (tidyeval)

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyeval

I've been struggling with implementation of Hadley's https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html for a while now and I can't get it to work for my purpose.

In my toy example, I want to write a function that would take as arguments two columns (column names are known) and run a t.test. The issue is that I cannot seem to be able to pass the column names to the t.test. Here it is:

```
df <- tibble(
names = LETTERS[1:10],
colA = rnorm(10),
colB = rnorm(10, 1, 2),
colC = rnorm(10, 3, 4)
)
```

And this is what I have in mind (note than I am using magrittr to extract columns as vectors directly):

```
myFun <- function(data, column_name1, column_name2) {
    data %$%
    t.test(column_name1, column_name2)$p.value
}
myFun(df, colA, colB) # doesn't work
```

Hadley's guide says that to parse the column names properly, we need to use quosure to "quote" the variable names and then "unquote" them when they are used in the function (he uses the words "dark magic" which sounds accurate to me). I interpreted it like this:

```
myFun <- function(data, column_name1, column_name2) {
    col1 <- enquo(column_name1)
    col2 <- enquo(column_name2)
    data %$%
    t.test(!!col1, !!col2)$p.value
}
myFun(df, colA, colB)
```

This, however, results in an error:

```
Error: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.

  # Bad:
  list(!!myquosure)

  # Good:
  dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)
```

Which I think means that I cannot use quosure with t.test (a non-tidyverse function)? So I abandoned my t.test for now and tried to see if just selecting the columns worked:

```
myFun <- function(data, column_name1, column_name2) {
    col1 <- enquo(column_name1)
    col2 <- enquo(column_name2)
    data %>%
    dplyr::select(!!col1, !!col2)
}
myFun(df, colA, colB)
```

This works. But then this:

```
myFun <- function(data, column_name1, column_name2) {
    col1 <- enquo(column_name1)
    col2 <- enquo(column_name2)
    data %>%
    dplyr::select(!!col1, !!col2) %$%
    t.test(col1, col2)$p.value
}
myFun(df, colA, colB)
```

doesn't, with an error `Error in t.test.formula(colA, colB) : 'formula' missing or incorrect` (even though I don't use a formula notation for the t.test). Just to be clear, this works fine: `df %$% t.test(colA, colB)$p.value`.

I would like to understand why passing the column names (which are selected correctly!) doesn't work in this function and, if this is a hopeless idea of running pairwise t.tests, what's a better solution? The end goal of this is a bigger function that would take an arbitrary set of numerical columns and run all pairwise t.tests possible.

Thanks!

kJ

Comment: Note that in respect to your end goal there's already a dedicated base function for running pairwise t tests (assuming you're only interested in the p.values), it's called....`pairwise.t.test()`.

Comment: Good catch, thanks! ...although upon reading the help it seems like pairwise.t.test assumes I want to t.tests in the formula notation (where my grouping variables are in a single column), so would not be applicable here, where I need to run one whole column against a whole other column.

Comment: No formula but yes, the data needs to be in long format with a grouping variable. `stack()` the data first (i.e. `stack(df[2:4])`.  It really is the easiest way to go about this.

Answer (score 3):

A few points:

- This guide is about interfacing with tidy eval functions. Instead, you're trying to create a new tidy eval function.
- It's a WIP that is not going to be finished because we've made tidy eval simpler and it no longer needs a book. I recommend going with the next version of the dplyr programming vignette: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/programming.html (remove the `/dev` from the URL once dplyr 1.0 is out).
- Going through `transmute()` or `select()` to take inputs and then working with the data frame is a nice approach.
- However interfacing with `select()` is best when you're working with multiple variables. Here you want to select one one, something that isn't validated by `select()`. The user could supply `starts_with()` as input for example.
- The main point missing from your function is that you haven't given constant names to the column, so that you can pick them up and supply them to `t.test()`.

I suggest something like (untested):

```
t_test <- function(data, col1, col2) {
  data <- data %>% transmute(
    col1 = {{ col1 }},
    col2 = {{ col2 }}
  )

  test <- t.test(data$col1, data$col2)
  test$p.value
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I do use select() with two variables and I don't understand what you mean by "aven't given constant names to the column". Regardless of the above, the bit that is confusing is that: `myFun <- function(data, column_name1, column_name2) {
    col1 <- enquo(column_name1)
    col2 <- enquo(column_name2)
    data %>%
    dplyr::select(!!col1, !!col2)
}` `myFun(df, colA, colB)` produces a two-column tibble that I can then pass onto t.test with %$%: `myFun(df, colA, colB) %$% t.test(colA, colB)` **works**. But when I put the same pipe and t.test inside the body of the function, it doesn't!

Comment: Your code works - thanks a lot! But if I have to address the columns with $ for the t.test anyway, the advantage of the tidyverse is mostly gone, I can just as well stick to base. Also - that new programming vignette is very different from the old one %-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the advantage of the data masking being gone. With this implementation, `t_test()` is a data masking function and the user doesn't have to use `$`. I thought this was your goal. Note that the implementation could eventually be simplified with https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/812 if we add it to rlang.

Comment: OK, fair enough, you are correct. I was just approaching this from a teaching perspective, ie teaching someone who only knows tidyverse on how to write a function like that. But that's a whole other level of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are close, try:

```
myfun <- function(data, c1, c2) {
  c1 <- enquo(c1)
  c2 <- enquo(c2)
  t.test(pull(data, !!c1), pull(data, !!c2))$p.value
}
myfun(df, colA, colB)
# [1] 0.1179605
```

The problem with your last version is, that you are passing a tibble to `t.test`, but need 2 vectors.

Comment: Nice use of `pull()`

Comment: Hi, yes, OK, but this purpose (passing tibble's columns as vectors) is achieved with the magrittr's special pipe %$%. This is why `df %$% t.test(colA, colB)$p.value` works, and `df %>% select(colA, colB) %$% t.test(colA, colB)$p.value` works. Somehow when I do it inside the function, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in base R with `deparse(substitute())`:

```r
myFun <- function(data, col1, col2) {
  t.test(data[[deparse(substitute(col1))]] , data[[deparse(substitute(col2))]])$p.value
}
```

Such that:

```
myFun(df, colA, colB)
#> [1] 0.01541674
```